# Slide a div from right to left using animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want a div `'.whole'` to animate (slide from right to left)

jQuery

```
$('#menu').click(function() {
      $('.whole').toggleClass('r2');
      $('#slideMenu').toggle();
});

.r2 { right: 200px }
```

I am not able to use the function animate() properly.

Comment: Well, what did your attempt with `animate` look like?

Comment: I did not know how to use it :)

I just want to animate .whole (slide from right to left)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#menu').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // because it is an anchor element
      $('.whole').animate({
          right: '200px'
      });
      $('#slideMenu').toggle();
});
```

But your `position` property should already be set in CSS or you might not get exactly what you need.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Abs5H/6/)

To explain: the function takes a JS object of properties, like this:

```
{
    right: '200px',
    somethingElse: 'value',
    myboolean: true
}
```

you can also assign this to a var and pass it to `animate`:

```
var cssProperties = { right: '200px' }

$('#menu').click(function() {
  $('.whole').animate(cssProperties);
});
```

You can pass other arguements as readable in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: I really like this example and it doesn't use absolute position which is awesome!!