# How do i make the green box only slide 90%

Tags: jquery, html

I would like the green box (`#box3`) to go only 90% to the right.  The box is directly inside the body element.

```
<div id='box1'>
    <div id='box2'>
    </div>
    <div id='box3'>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$( "#box1" ).click(function() { $( "#box3" ).toggle("slide",
```

```
#box1 {
    background-color: white;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
#box2 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
#box3 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: may be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208402/slide-a-div-from-right-to-left-using-animate/16208453#16208453

Comment: the problem i found with .animate is it doesnt take the containing divs wit the container div

Comment: That was typo error use `#box3` instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery animation instead:

```
// define left position, I used defined 80%
<div id='box3' style="left:80%">

<script>
      $( "#box1" ).click(function() { 
            $('#box3').animate({left:'90%'},"fast","swing");
      } );
</script>  


// this is box 3

#box3
{
    position:relative;
    background-color: green;
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a button, click on it and it will take the box to the right 90% of the way (but the position should be "absolute")

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({left:"90%"}, "slow");
    });
    });
</script> 
</head>`

<body>

// click the button

<button> Box 3 </button>
<div style=background-color: "green"; height: "600px"; width: "300px"; float: "left"; position:"absolute";>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I keep seeing everyone use the .animate but the issue with it is if i throw a couple boxes into the gren boxes those boxes will remain when the animation is called and not animate with the container element. is there a way to to take all the containing elements in with it so it appears the same as when you use a toggle and still only go 90%?