# How to slide a td from right to left on mouseover and slide back on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-slider

I have an html page which has been divided in single row and two columns. 1st columns has been given a width of 90% and 2nd column 10%.

When page loads I want that 2nd column should be hidden completely and on whole page there should be the content of 1st column.

But when I move my mouse towards that 10% of page on the right side. The content of that td should be come as sliding and when I moved out mouse it should slide back(hide) to the right.

I am trying to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.height = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
  $( "#side" ).mouseover(function() {
    document.getElementById("map-canvas").className = "OverlayEffect";
    $( "#map-canvas" ).animate({
      width: "100%"
    });
  });
  $( "#side" ).mouseout(function() {
    $( "#map-canvas" ).animate({
      width: "90%"
    });
  });
});
```

Html:

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td width="90%" id="map">
         <!--  start  Loading Fancy Box handling -->
         <div id="modalMsg">
            <br /> <br /> <imgsrc="../DiagnosticDrop4/static/images/ajax-loader.gif" /> <br /> <br />
         </div>
         <!--  end  Loading Fancy Box handling -->
         <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </td>
      <td width="10%" class="Sidebar" id="side">
         <div id="map-canvas1">
            <a id='link' href='../DiagnosticDrop4/san.html'>
               <h3>
               <center>Add/Delete SAN</center>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div id="map-canvas2">
            <a id='alink' href='../DiagnosticDrop4/ParamIntervalDetails'>
               <h3>
               <center>24hr Dashboard</center>
            </a>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show you markup and what have you tried ?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208402/

Comment: @Varun Jindal we should code it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i made it works the way you want it to

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#side" ).hide();

            $("body").on("mousemove",function(event) {
                if (event.pageX >= $( document ).width() - 50) {
                    $( "#map" ).width('0%');
                    $( "#side" ).width('100%');
                    $( "#side" ).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $( "#map" ).width('100%');
                    $( "#side" ).width('0%');
                    $( "#side" ).hide();    
                }
            });

        });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td width="90%" id="map">
                <!--  start  Loading Fancy Box handling -->
                    <div id="modalMsg">
                    <br /> <br /> <imgsrc="../DiagnosticDrop4/static/images/ajax-loader.gif" /> <br /> <br />
                    </div> <!--  end  Loading Fancy Box handling -->

                    <div id="map-canvas">

                    </div>
                </td>

                <td width="10%" class="Sidebar" id="side">
                    <div id="map-canvas1">
                        <a id='link' href='../DiagnosticDrop4/san.html'><h3>
                        <center>Add/Delete SAN</center></a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="map-canvas2">
                        <a id='alink' href='../DiagnosticDrop4/ParamIntervalDetails'><h3>
                        <center>24hr Dashboard</center></a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if (event.pageX >= $( document ).width() - 50) //this code does the trick of if the mouse has reach the end of the screen to the right and is just 50px less it triggers it

Comment: the logic is complete you just need to import a smooth css library and add in your animate code to do the slide effect for you ;)

Comment: Its not working for me, on mouseover the td on the right side should overlap the previous content and on mouseout it should be back as it is. Does jquery provide sliding functionality ?

Comment: yes it does animate would do the trick for you but the above code is more like a base you can put your animate code inside to give a smoother look

Comment: when you tried my code is it even showing div when you move your cursor to the end of the screen as in far right ???