# jquery .animate() sliding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sliding is coming from center because i have given `width:100%; left: 50%; .`

Slide is coming from left to right, but i want this to start from right to left. I suspect this is a CSS issue. I tried changing CSS but nothing helps. Please someone locate the mistake and help me to proceed. Thanks

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BMYW9/4/)

**Css Code:**

```
.sidebar_list
{
float:left;
display: none;
position: fixed;
width:100%;
top: 57px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 50%;
right: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
line-height: 2em;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
height: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
background: #33B5E5;
}



 $(".logo").click(function()
    {
        $(".sidebar_list").animate({
                    width: 'toggle'
                }, 200)
                });
```

Comment: Maybe [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16208453/3433782) helps you

Answer (score 1):

remove `left:50%` from your css. It works

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMYW9/5/)